# Connect vagrant machine to virtualBox

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox, git-bash

Hi i am trying to set up my git Bash enviroment with vagrant via virtualBox but i am unsuccessfull. I am trying to open localhost:8080/xxxx, but it just loads and I think this is because this

I have the latest versions of both vagrant and virtualBox.
My commands:
"cd fullstack/vagrant", 
"vagrant up"

but then i get the following :

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   ==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' is up to date...
>   ==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
>   ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>   ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
>       default: Adapter 1: nat
>   ==> default: Forwarding ports...
>       default: 8000 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
>       default: 8080 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
>       default: 5000 (guest) => 5000 (host) (adapter 1)
>       default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
>   ==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
>   ==> default: Booting VM...
>   ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
>       default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
>       default: SSH username: vagrant
>       default: SSH auth method: private key Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that Vagrant was unable to communicate
>   with the guest machine within the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout"
>   value) time period.
>
> If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that Vagrant
>   had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors are
>   usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
>   working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
>   problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes. Verify
>   that authentication configurations are also setup properly, as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
>   the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved. For anyone with a similar problem:

I reinstalled both programs but this time I initialized a box within vagrant. I just picked the most popular from here: https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search